# Current User Information in Angular9

Tags: angular

How can I get current Login User Information in Angular 9????????????
 I am new on web development and working on a project in Angular 9. I successfully logined by providing username and password. Now I want to get current user id but in this task I am failed.Please any one can guide me how can I get current user id or current user profile from database and to store this information in the local storage. Code of my login.component.ts is here

```
import { AppConstants } from './../../private/AppConstants';
import { BadInput } from './../../../common/ErrorHandler/badInput';
import { AuthService } from '../../private/Services/auth.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AppError } from '../../../common/ErrorHandler/appError';
import { toBase64String } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/source_map';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';


@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  invalidLogin: boolean = false;
  userName: string;
  constructor(
    private route: Router,
    private router: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService) {

  }

  errorFlag: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;

  ngOnInit() { }

  signIn(credentials) {
    this.errorFlag = false;
    this.authService.blockUI.start();
    this.authService.login(credentials)
      .subscribe(
      resp => {
          let returnUrl = this.router.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnURL');
          if (resp !== undefined && resp["access_token"]) {
            localStorage.setItem(AppConstants.userInfo , resp["access_token"] );
            localStorage.setItem("message","Welcome Sajid");
            localStorage.setItem("userid",resp["access_id"]);
            this.route.navigate([returnUrl || '/']);
          }
          else this.invalidLogin = true;
          this.authService.blockUI.stop();
        },
        (error) => {
          this.authService.blockUI.stop();
          if (error instanceof BadInput) {
            //alert(error.message);
            this.errorMessage = error.message;
          }
          //else throw error;
          else if (error.status === 400) {
            //alert(error.json().error_description);
            this.errorMessage = error.json().error_description;
          }
          this.errorFlag = true;
        }
      );
  }
}



My service code is given below
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppConstants } from './../AppConstants';
import { NotFoundError } from '../../../common/ErrorHandler/notFoundError';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AppError } from '../../../common/ErrorHandler/appError';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment'
import { BadInput } from '../../../common/ErrorHandler/badInput';
import { NgBlockUI, BlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient){
     this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   this.options = {headers  : this.headers};
   }
  private headers;
  private options; 
  @BlockUI() blockUI: NgBlockUI;

  login(credentials)
  {

     return this.http.post( environment.authURL +  "token", 
     "grant_type=password&username="+ credentials.userName + "&password=" + credentials.password +
      "&client_id="+ environment.clientId ,this.options);
  }

  logout()
  {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

isLogedIn()
{
  let userInfo = localStorage.getItem(AppConstants.userInfo);
  if(userInfo !== undefined && userInfo !== null) 
  {
   //let expiryDate : Date = new Date(userInfo[".expires"]);
   //if (expiryDate > new Date()) return true;
   // Implement Refresh token Logic here as well ...........
   return true;
  }

  return false;
}

currentUser()
{
  let userInfo = localStorage.getItem(AppConstants.userInfo);
  return userInfo;
}

private ErrorHandler(error : Response)
{
  if(error.status === 404)
  {
    //return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
  }
  if(error.status === 400)
  {
    ///return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json().error_description));
  }
  //return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
}

}
```

Comment: By seeing your post method, you should send your credential in json body format not query param. Second thing your api should also return details of user which you want to store it in localstorage, if credentials are proper

Answer (score 0):

Validate in backend using username and password return data or error based on result and this will help for login

```
.subscribe(
      data => {
          // Add successfull usl Headers;          
      },
      error =>{
        //rediredt to login page
      }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your response of POST API call.

If your post API returns user info and access_token after successful validation. then in your component you can just subscribe to it as below (which you are already doing)

```js
 this.authService.login(credentials).subscribe((response: any) => {
  // save user info
})
```

If your API redirects back to the UI upon successful validation with returnURL appending access_token (http://localhost:4200?returnUrl=someUrl&access_token=jwt), you can try the below code.

Service code

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class AuthService {
  helper = new JwtHelperService();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(route => {
      if (route.has('returnUrl') && route.has('access_token')) {
        this.login(route.get('access_token'));
        this.router.navigate(['returnUrl'])
      }
    });
  }

  login(token: string): boolean {
    const tokenExpired = this.helper.isTokenExpired(token);
    if (token && !tokenExpired) {
       const userInfoFromToken = this.helper.decodeToken(token);
      // save user info to localstorage
    } else {
     // logic to logout
    }
  }

}
```